# grunt-spritesmith and load-grunt-config doesn't work

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, sprite, grunt-spritesmith

When I run task:

> grunt sprite

I receive this error:

> jit-grunt: Plugin for the "sprite" task not found.
>   If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
>   See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings
>
> Warning: Task "sprite" failed. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

Grunfile.js & --config-debug here:
https://gist.github.com/JosephWM/c43530246cc0ba5d060a

All tasks works fine, but I cannot run grunt-spritesmith. Please help.

**update:** problem solved. U can see code of changed files here (link in comment)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/JosephWM/2ddcd3c8600efdbbc732

Comment: u should post that as an answer, and accept it for making it easy for others to find your solution!